# What is a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

This question is rather pedantic, but it is something that has been bothering me for some time.

Summing up infinitely many terms of a sequence is something that is done in pretty much every subfield of mathematics, so series are right at the core of mathematics. But strangely, I have never seen a formal definition of a series of the form "A series is...", whether I look in books on calculus or on Banach space theory.

Also, the use of language seems somewhat inconsistent. Many texts formally define $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ to be $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n$ but then write something like "The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges if...", which would then mean "$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n$ converges if...", which makes no sense for then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is either a number (or a vector) or a meaningless expression such as "the largest natural number".

So what is the definition of a series? Or are series really just a way to speak about sequences and series do not exist as mathematical objects?

Comment: I view it as a special sort of sequence, i.e. the sequence of partial sums of a sequence of numbers. The definition of a series basically says this, right? I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @Lost1 That would make a series exactly the same thing as sequence (in a commutative group). And as I wrote, I didn't find a formal definition.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker  What is the problem if they are the same? It is useful to have a name that matches better the application at hand.

Comment: @SergioParreiras The problem is that the way the word series is used is not really compatible with a formal definition as a sequence of partial sums, as in the example given.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: yes you are right, people use the word series sometimes to denote a sequence of partial sums and other times to denote the limit of this sequence.

Comment: We could say that it's the pair $(a_k,s_n)$ where $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$, I guess. That's the way I was taught at least. To represent the pair we write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$, and we say it converges if  $\exists \ \lim s_n$. I suppose this way it is in fact different to just a sequence, as it's a pair of sequences.

Comment: Oh! also a series can be a completely formal object, if it's a power series. That is, an expression, nothing more, of the type $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_nx^n$, with a certain algebra (in the set of formal power series).

Comment: @GPerez If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ represents the pair $(a_k, s_n)$, then it should depend on $k$ and $n$ (but the symbol does not show it). Usually, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is used to denote the limit of the partial sums which is a number.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar I think it's a perfectly formal representation, if one understands what $a_k$ and $s_n$ are, in terms of each other. Similarly, for example, one can write $\int_D \omega$ and know if its a double, triple, etc. integral, if one knows what $D$ and $\omega$ are.

Comment: @GPerez Sorry, I misunderstood the terms $a_k$ and $s_n$ (usually written as $\{a_k\}$ for the sequence) as just particular numbers in the sequence. Your definition of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ makes sense but then what is your notation of the actual limit of the partial sums?

Comment: @PratyushSarkar The same hahah, so it may be an abuse of notation

Answer (score 7):

I think I remember that when I first learned about this, my professor said that this is the first 'abuse of notation' that we would encounter- the symbol $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is *both* used for the sequence and its limit.

One way to answer your original question could be to think of a series as a pair of sequences $(a_n,b_n)$ such that $b_{n+1}-b_n=a_n$ and so make both the underlying sequence and the series to part of the data.

Answer (score 4):

The question has nothing to do with infinity; you might just as well ask, what is a *finite* series, or, what is a polynomial?

The **sum** of an infinite series is the limit of its sequence of partial sums, but that doesn't mean that the infinite series is its sequence of partial sums. That's not the way the term "series" is used; it is the kind of nonsense you might get from a mathematics instructor who is being pressed for a formal definition.

The answer is that a series, like a polynomial, is a **formal expression**. We all know what a formal expression is; for most mathematical purposes there is no need to identify it with a particular set-theoretical object. What is a polynomial? You might choose to identify a polynomial (in one variable, over the real field) with its sequence of coefficients, and so define it as a function from the set of all nonnegative integers to the set of all real numbers which takes nonzero values at most a finite number of times. Or you could define a polynomial as a word in a certain language over an alphabet containing variables, numerals, $+$ and $-$ signs, etc.

Comment: "We all know what a formal expression is" I don't. What is a formal expression?

Answer (score 3):

A *series* is the sequence of partial sums of another sequence.

The *sum* of a series is the limit of the sequence of partial sums, if it exists.

Just like you can write a sequence as $(a_n)$, it may help to write the corresponding series as $\sum a_n$. Note the absence of decoration in the sum sign.

The sum of a series is denoted $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ just as the limit of a sequence is denoted $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

The precise definition is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$$